# KVM: Virtio net - зависает сеть

Tags: виртуальная-машина, виртуализация, kvm

Win2008R2 перестает получать/передавать пакеты через vitio интерфейс (обычно через 2-4 часа после перезагрузки). Пинг тоже не проходит. Помогает перезагрузка гостевой ОС или *изменение настроек* сетевого интерфейса в `Диспетчере устройств`.

При использовании `e1000` всё ок, но страдает производительность (`500 мбит/с` между ВМ-Хост по `iperf3`). 
С Linux в качестве гостевой ОС проблема с virtio-net не наблюдается.

Что делать?

Хост: `Ubuntu 17.04, qemu-kvm 2.8, libvirtd (libvirt) 2.5.0, virt-manager`

Гость: `Windows 2008 R2`, проверял драйвера `virtio-win-0.1.135` и `virtio-win-0.1.126`

Comment: Бриджы в госте есть? Сетевые штуки от гипер-в  не устанавливал?
virtio виснет от захвата пакетов с интерфейса. Встречал несколько раз такое, вот например https://github.com/coova/coova-chilli/issues/253

Comment: @eri Неа, спец.ПО нет, мостов тоже нет (в госте). Трафик гоняется в основном UDP, 10-12 мбит/с